# How to reload Radzen DataGrid manually without refreshing page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, blazor, radzen

I created a button to reload a Radzen DataGrid on Blazor.

The datagrid is supposed to be reloaded after I click the button.

However, nothing happened when I clicked the button.

**Button**

```
<RadzenButton Click=@(args => Refresh()) Icon="refresh" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" />
```

**Radzen DataGrid**

```
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="grid" Data="@records" TItem="class" ...>
```

**Blazor Coding**

```
IEnumerable<class> records;
RadzenDataGrid<class> grid = new RadzenDataGrid<class>();

async Task Refresh() 
{ 
    records = Service.GetAllRecords();
    await grid.Reload();
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

**Service**

```
public List<class> GetAllRecords() 
    {
        return _db.records.Include(r => r.a).Include(r => r.b).OrderByDescending(r=>r.id).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Is `records = Service.GetAllRecords();` really a sync method that runs to completion before the next step?  It would appear that records isn't updated before the rest of the code in `Refresh` completes.  Can you show `GetAllRecords`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated my question. I think I am facing the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MrC aka Shaun Curtis is correct. 
Simply change the codes of `GetAllRecords` and  make it an `async` function. 
Then use `await` in `Refresh()`. 
It would work.